# use Mobx store in Navigation header

Tags: react-native, mobx, react-native-navigation, mobx-react

```
//{Imports Here}

 const LoggedOut = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
  }
});

const LoggedIn = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation}) => ({
      headerRight: (
        <View style={[styles.alternativeLayoutButtonContainer]}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate("SelectFlag");
            }}
          >
            <Text
              style={[
                styles.awesomePhone,
                store.user.agent.calling
                  ? (style = { color: "#444" })
                  : (style = { color: "red" })
              ]}
            >
              &#xf095;
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      )
    }),

 SelectFlag: {
    screen: SelectFlag,
    navigationOptions: { header: null }
  }
  //{Other Screens here}
});



const App = ({ store }) =>
  store.user.isLoggedIn ? <LoggedIn /> : <LoggedOut />;

export default inject("store")(observer(App));
```

this is my code and i am desperately trying to use a value out of the Mobx store (store.user.agent.calling) to check if someone is calling or not.

i tried:

```
//navigationOptions: ({ navigation, store}) => ({
```

and tried to @inject it somehow to the TouchableOpacity but i ran out of ideas to fix it

... well I tried more than its two things but in my head this two seemed the most logical reasonable ones.

sorry i this is a dumb question but i´m really new to Mobx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well I stoped trying to inject it somehow direktly to the component and i packed in a seperate class like this:

```
//{Imports here}

 @inject("store")
 export default class IncommingCall extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <View>
         <TouchableOpacity
           onPress={() => {
             navigation.navigate("SelectFlag");
           }}
         >
           <Text
             style={[
               styles.awesomePhone,
               !this.props.store.user.agent.calling
                 ? (style = { color: "#444" })
                 : (style = { color: "red" })
             ]}
           >
             &#xf095;
           </Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: I found this answer - thought no way...  there has to be a better way... two days of trying various hacks and fixes and this is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The React navigation api has changed a fair bit since this question was posted, however for those having difficulty making the header or screenOptions in general reactive to mobx state change the key is to wrap the component that returns the stack navigator in `observer`.

Then passing store in e.g. from the parent `NavigationContainer` to the stack E.g.:

```
const MyStack = createStackNavigator();
const MyStackScreens = (store) => observer(() => (
  <MyStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerStyle: { height: store.height } }}>
    <MyStack.Screen
      name="..."
      component={...}
    />
  </MyStack.Navigator>
);
```